# Want to create StackDriver dashboard from template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

Is it possible to create StackDriver dashboards programmatically from a declarative template (similar to how Google Cloud Deployment allows you to create and manage cloud resources)?

We use a different GCP project for each of our environments (master, staging, prod) and want to have StackDriver dashboards with the same metrics in each project.

I checked the [StackDriver Monitoring API docs](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/) as well as the [Cloud Deployment supported resources](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/create-configuration-file#supported_resource_types_and_properties) and did not find any evidence of support for this use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a Product Manager with Stackdriver.  There's not currently a public available dashboard API.  Until that's available, one solution many of our customers use is to create a canonical dashboard template and then copy this each time a new one is needed, modifying the input data.  [image: Copy a Canonical Dashboard]

Comment: is providing a API in the roadmap for Stackdriver? if so any ETA?

Comment: Yes, API support for Dashboards in Stackdriver is on our roadmap.  I don't have a public ETA that I can share, but we're working hard on this now!

Comment: any update on API for creating stackdriver dashboards.

Comment: how can I copy a dashboard from one project to another?

Comment: @MaryKoes is this still on the roadmap or should we plan for something else?

Comment: We're also in need for a way to copy one dashboard into another different projects. We have dev, test and production environments

Comment: There is an API now. See https://medium.com/google-cloud/part-2-building-a-dashboard-for-a-data-processing-pipeline-with-the-stackdriver-dashboard-api-69e3260b5ec3 for an Introduction.